# Removing "post page" from Wordpress completely

Tags: wordpress, blogs, searchbar

Me and my colleagues are trying to figure out how to remove a link from a website we are building using Wordpress. Our customer is blind and is using a program that reads everything on the website to him. As we are tabbing through the menubar we find something that leads us to a page called "/?s=". And on this page we can see the websites blog posts. Even if we have tried to follow the guides online on how to remove blog post completely. Putting the post page to -select- instead of any page at all. But it does not work. Maybe it is the search bar? Although we have removed that as well.

This is an unnecessary stage for him and can be very confusing. Would love if someone could help us?

Please tell me if I can explain it better!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! There might be a chance to remove the link (or the code that creates it) from your wordpress theme/template. However, to me `/?s=` looks like a placeholder for searching (`<your-url>/?s=foobar` when you enter "foobar" in the search field).